# C++ Structs and Dynamically Allocated Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

This is what I have so far. When I try to add an item to the Array, the program crashes. I'm looking for it to ultimately store the item, along with getting the current time, and mark the item as not completed until the user enters 'done'.

Can't use - standard containers or smart pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

struct List{
    string items;
    char completed;
    int time_t;

};

int main()
{
    // Declare Variables
    int userChoice = 0;
    int numItems = 0;
    int count = 0;
    List* list = new List[];

    // Get current time
    time_t recordedTime = time(nullptr);
    tm localTime = *localtime(&recordedTime);

    // Give the user some options
    cout << "1. Add Item" << endl;
    cout << "2. Remove Item" << endl;
    cout << "3. Sort Items" << endl;
    cout << "4. Mark as Completed" << endl;
    cout << "5. Exit" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number of the operation you wish to perform: ";
    cin >> userChoice;
    cout << endl;

    // Perform the operation
    switch(userChoice)
    {
    case 1:
        {
            cin.ignore(50, '\n');
            cout << "Enter one item per line, or enter 'done' to finish\n";

        while(true)
        {
            do{
                count++;
                cout << "Item" << count << ": ";
                getline(cin, list[count].items);
            }
            while(list[count].items !="done");

            if(list[count].items == "done")
            {
                break;
            }
          }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        {

        }
        break;
    case 3:
        {

        }
        break;
    case 4:
        {
            cout << "Item #: ";
        }
        break;
    case 5:
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    // Output the list
    cout << "-------Items-------" << endl;

    cout << "Enter the number of the operation you wish to perform: ";
    cin >> userChoice;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no array in your code.

Comment: You are using subscript indirection on a pointer to a single structure.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? **If you got an exception or error, post the line it occurred on and the details.** Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Error I'm getting is in the debug which is <Error reading characters of string> on line 24

Comment: `List* list = new List[];` is ill-formed  (a few comments suggest this allocates a 1-sized list but that is not true)

Comment: You should really take a look at a book about data structures in C++. I don't see any arrays in your code, so until you understand what an array is and how to use it, there's no way to help without writing the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is you should use `vector` to contain all your items. but that will change your code a lot.

the easier way is change your List definition to 
`List* list = new List[1000];`
this will alloc an array with size 1000, your previous definition just alloc one `List`, and use pointer `list` points to it.

**EDIT**

if you do not know size, you should use `vector` define your list as `vector<List> list`, and use `push_back` to append item to container.

like

```
{
    cout << "Item" << count << ": ";
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    List item {str, 'N', localtime};
    list.push_back(move(item));
}
```

**EDIT**

cannot use stl, and only limitation of memory, I think you have to change your `List` definition to a `LinkedList`, like

```
struct List{
    string items;
    char completed;
    int time_t;
    List* next;
};
```

and allocate memory every time when you input, you have to have another pointer to remember last item you inputted. 
you will have hard time to sort if you do not use stl.

Comment: The problem is that I need the array to hold an unlimited number of items (only limited by memory).

Comment: I failed to mention that for this specific project, we can't use any standard containers like std::vector

Comment: @bradym55 you will need to resize your array from time to time as needed